# match column'cells to other if got find datediffence

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, query-builder

this morning i involved by this query . i wasted my 2 days . but not got good solution . I have a mysql query

```
SELECT l.date_entered, n.date_entered, n.date_modified, n.name, n.parent_id
FROM  `notes` AS n, leads AS l
WHERE n.parent_type =  "Leads" && MONTH( l.date_entered ) =1 && YEAR( l.date_entered ) =2013 &&  
n.parent_id = l.id
ORDER BY n.date_modified ASC
```

This is giving me this output:-

```
date_entered date_entered date_modified         name    parent_id
2013-01-07  2013-01-07    2013-01-07 20:17:44   rahul   100   
2013-01-07  2013-01-07    2013-01-07 22:27:38   rawat   101
2013-01-03  2013-01-07    2013-01-07 23:29:02   rohit   102
2013-01-03  2013-01-07    2013-01-07 23:33:55   mamta   100
2013-01-04  2013-01-08    2013-01-08 06:16:11   kiran   101
2013-01-07  2013-01-08    2013-01-08 07:10:10   ajay    100
```

Now, I am trying to get the `date-modified` difference by matching on `parent_id` e.g.

1. Starting with 100, search returns another 100 in 4th row. This date-modified the same day, so result = 0
2. Next search is for 101 which is found in 5th row. This date-modified is 1 day after the previous 101, so result = 1
3. Next search is for 102, which is not found, so skip it
4. Next search is for 100,  but this has already been found, so skip it
5. Next search is for 101,  but this has already been found, so skip it
6. Next search is for 100,  but this has already been found, so skip it

my output will be such as:-

```
date_entered date_entered date_modified         name    parent_id   datediff
2013-01-07  2013-01-07    2013-01-07 20:17:44   rahul   100         0
2013-01-07  2013-01-07    2013-01-07 22:27:38   rawat   101         1
2013-01-03  2013-01-07    2013-01-07 23:29:02   rohit   102         not found
2013-01-03  2013-01-07    2013-01-07 23:33:55   mamta   100         skip due to previous match
2013-01-04  2013-01-08    2013-01-08 06:16:11   kiran   101         skip due to previous match 
2013-01-07  2013-01-08    2013-01-08 07:10:10   ajay    100         skip due to previous match
```

Comment: Sorry chum, I can't follow this - what is your objective and what are the criterion for achieving it? Why is datediff 1 for the 2nd line of output (rawat)?

Comment: First search by starting 100 . got other 100 in 4th row. then this forth row date-modified will be less by previous 100. so result= 0  and then again search for 101 by starting row or first row. and got 101 in 5th row then less this 5th row date-modified with previous 101 rows.

Comment: and then search for 102 and do not got 102 so skip it or write 1 also

Comment: and then search for 100 but this is already searched so skip it

Comment: and then search for 101 but it is also searched previous so skip it

Comment: and finally search for 100 byt it is also searched prevous os skip it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this :

```
CREATE  TABLE test as 
(SELECT l.date_entered date1, n.date_entered date2, n.date_modified mod_date, n.name name, n.parent_id parentid
FROM  `notes` AS n, leads AS l
WHERE n.parent_type =  "Leads" && MONTH( l.date_entered ) =1 && YEAR( l.date_entered ) =2013 &&  
n.parent_id = l.id);

select *,
case 
when mod_date=b.min_date and count_parent_id>1 then cast( datediff(next_date,b.min_date) as char)

when count_parent_id=1 then 'not found'
else 'skip due to previous match'
end datediff

 from  
(SELECT Date1, Date2, mod_date, name, parentid
FROM  test) as a
left join 

(select min_date,next_date, count_parent_id, q1.parentid
  from
    (SELECT min(mod_date) min_date, count(parentid) count_parent_id, parentid
    FROM  test 
    group by parentid) q1
   join
    (SELECT min(mod_date) next_date, parentid
    FROM  test 
    where  mod_date not in 
      (SELECT min(mod_date) min_date FROM  test 
      group by parentid)
    group by parentid
    )q2
   on q1.parentid=q2.parentid

) as b

on a.parentid=b.parentid
ORDER BY mod_date ASC ;

drop table test;
```

This works. Check [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/21f59/1)

Comment: thank u but i got  Incorrect parameter count in the call to native function 'datediff'

Comment: Duplicate column name 'date_entered'

Comment: again got - Duplicate column name 'date_entered'. there is two date_entered so please remove first date_entered.

Comment: tested but not got any result

Comment: thx , my parent-id column is contain values in varchar() such as 84590116-094c-7da8-6d81-4ecb683e51b5,  c181d043-b6a9-2d78-2972-4ed35f3a15fe  etc so it will be match instead of 100,101,102.... plz check .

Comment: empty result got :) please your query is looking very good but not got result

Comment: please remove date-entered column and also date-modified and try for name and datediff

Comment: thank but still not got result . i will do it . if result will get . accept it

Comment: datediff is not working . i am trying to find the diff between datemodified. it is always show to 0. plz check

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/3689f5/1 plz check here . datediff should be 11 of parentid 100

Comment: I am unable to do complete . have you got any solution plz

Comment: thank you . i am something confuse about table name and column . please edit it by my above query . you can take table name column name by above query . please sir

Comment: @RahulRawat This is the simplest suggestion as i donot have your data. You can use temporary table instead of actual table. Hope this helps.